# Can I post here for hobby project recruitment?

Tags: support

I don't want to break rules and I couldn't find any useful information if it is possible to post here for hobby project recruitment.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't. But thanks for asking first :)

That's out of the scope of gamedev.stackexchange, and Stack Exchange at large.

There is a forum section about that in [GDNet](https://www.gamedev.net/): [Hobby Project Classifieds](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/forum/29-hobby-project-classifieds/). This forum is more appropriate for this type of question.

---

You can take a look at [this help page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [this help page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Basically, recruiting is not an issue in the sense SO sees it, it's too broad and doesn't have a definitive answer.

Comment: I suspect the answer to this will also be 'no', but could OP instead ask about how to recruit for a hobby project?

Comment: @Pikalek That's a good question! I think it's border-line too broad or opinion based. There is a [tag:hiring], and not all questions are closed (yet). Maybe there is a way to ask it that would not invite users to answers with link-only answers.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Exchange is a question and answer site; so, as already stated, it is not an appropriate platform to post job recruitment.

On one side, you could seek out forums. However, it is entirely possible that you specifically wish to ask our users, whether it be due to previous interaction, or previous answers they have posted.

If that is the case, you also have the option of directly chatting with users you would like to work with in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=gamedev.stackexchange.com), once you have earned the requirement of 20 reputation points.