# Do recruitment requests need to be explicitly addressed in our help section?

Tags: discussion

Comments on [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/157897/unpaidhobbylooking-for-talented-developers) raised the issue that recruitment doesn't appear to be clearly mentioned in the on-topic & off-topic rules.

My question is: should it be explicitly covered? Does it come up enough to warrant coverage beyond meta?

I realize we cannot exhaustively list everything that is & is not in bounds for the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an extra bullet in a currently-reasonable-brief list, so I added it (with a link to [this](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/can-i-post-here-for-hobby-project-recruitment) meta post).

Comment: Thanks! I'll leave this open a bit to invite other viewpoints.